# I'm having trouble setting up this div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Currently I have an image/img tag that is 1920 x 1080 posted on my [Site](http://gulfstate.us/) (the first image displayed of the city).

I now want to style a `<p>` a `<button>` and a click-able phone number on the the image so I figured that I have to turn it into a `<div>` and use the image as a background.

When I tried `background:url(image/Houston_remodeling.jpg) center no-repeat;` on the div in order to achieve the way that the image is displayed/scaled as you adjust the browser size (on current website, gulfstate.us), the image is displayed zoomed in to the top corner and doesn't look pretty.

If any one can please help I would be very grateful. I am new to this so let me know what else I need to supply and I'll comment right back.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Add minimal code so we can help you

Comment: Or even an online example.

Comment: _"this <div>"_ where is it??

Comment: Can you guys just tell me how I would code the background in my div so it would have the same scalability as what is has on the current site? the style I have now is 'background:url(image/Houston_remodeling.jpg) center no-repeat;'

Comment: @user3145782 Just create a JSFiddle and we can have a look for you. We're not going to guess.

Comment: @Ruddy hope this helps http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/842/mq4r.jpg/ http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/607/0xqv.jpg/      http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/23/sbwr.jpg/     http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/14/7y2l.jpg/

Comment: @RafaEl check out the links

Comment: perhaps you just need to add `height:100%;`?

Comment: @RafaEl add that where?

Comment: So how do you want it to react to resizing? You haven't really said.

Comment: @rudy the current version of the site that is online (www.gulfstate.us) has it scale the way I want but it is set up an an img tag not a div. i want it in a div so that i can add a some text, a button and a phone number in there.

Comment: @user3145782 agree with Ruddy. but you may check Mihey's answer below, maybe thats what you want

Comment: @user3145782 Check out Mihey and my answers. I think it is the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done some modifications
Following will work fine,

Replace the your img tag with this.but its a hack , better to use css background-size

```
<div style="position:realtive;left:0;top:0">
   <div style="position: relative;top:0;z-index: 1;">
      <img class="headimg" src="image/Houston_remodeling.jpg">
   </div>
   <div style="position:absolute;top: 100px;left: 50%;z-index: 2;">
    9999999999999999999999999
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: that works but it seems to make it not take up any room on the page.. Instead of the rest of the page continuing after it, it is generated behind the div

Comment: I didn't tested in all browsers and in mobile, be make sure to test in all environments, other than that there is no problem here

Comment: how can i do this http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/440/31dc.jpg/ given your technique?

Comment: hey a quick Demo here, you need to tweak the css as per your design ,   http://jsfiddle.net/jKnbL/

Comment: try in your html page and tweak the css

Comment: is works but once the screen is reduced to phone size the content that is within drops out of the div like such http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/198/0lpy.jpg/ any ideas how to push that up a bit so that dosnt happen when the screen becomes smaller?

Comment: I reduced the margin of '.inner-cont' to 150px.. that worked fine on smaller screens but stayed further up on larger ones.. any way i can code it to be centered depending on '.outer-cont' size?

Answer (score 1):

Try `background-size: cover;`
From spec.

> Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the
>   background area is completely covered by the background image. Some
>   parts of the background image may not be in view within the background
>   positioning area

Answer (score 0):

As we are kinda guessing here I will just have a couple random guesses.

This way is using `background-size: cover;`, as I was writing this I see someone has already suggested it but as I have a example I may as well continue.

### HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <p>This is test text</p>
    <p><a>Phone Number: 0000-00000</a></p>
    <button>Test button</button>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
html,body {
    width: 100%;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 600px;
    min-height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9998;
    background: url(http://www.3dwallz.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/21/ice-city-lake-wallpapers-x.jpg) center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Take a look and see if that's how you want it to react to resizing, give feedback if its not and we will have another go.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/fLutG/)

**Note:** *After looking at the website you have linked to, I would suggest using this method for your `div` background. It is a lot cleaner and looks overall more professional.*

Comment: @rudy This actually works beautifully with only one thing that I cant get working. the min and max height dose't seem to change the height of the div like the current version on my site does. any way to add that feature? to be more specific, on a larger screen or my desktop the div is almost the full size of the browser and on the phone it is about half or so. I want to keep this feature. thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3145782 Could you not just base the `div` height off a percentage. e.g: `height: 25%;`. [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/fLutG/2/) Note: Should really look into using media tags for phones etc.

Comment: @rudy the way that its coded in there if i do that it makes it x% of the containing div, which makes it funky.

Comment: @user3145782 Erm, not 100% sure without seeing all the code that's affecting it. As you can see by my second example it does work.

Answer (score 0):

quick demo you need to tweak the css as per your design , 
       www.jsfiddle.net/jKnbL